# I can't seem to find what's wrong. It gives me no error message, but instead just ends the process without printing the wanted message

Tags: python

I can't seem to find what's wrong. It gives me no error message, but instead just ends the process without printing the wanted message

```
def choose_chracter_class():
  character_class_option = raw_input()
  return character_class_option
  if character_class_option is str("mage") or str("Mage"):
    print "Mage, sorcerers who wield mass amounts of magic energy to cause  havoc among their opponents, summon entities, or protect themselves from harm."
    print "Attack - 5"
    print "Magic Atk - 30"
    print "Defence - 10"
    print "Magic Def - 15"
    print "Speed - 10"
  if chracter_class_option is str("warrior") or str("Warrior"):
    print "Warrior"
  else:
    print character_class_option + " isn't an option"
choose_chracter_class()
```

Comment: You return in the second line of the function. The rest of the function will not run after you return.  Also, don't use `if ... is ... or ...`. It doesn't do what you think. Instead use something like `if character_class_option.lower() == 'mage':`

Comment: There are two separate problems with `is` and `or` -- `is` compares object identity not equivalence, and the `or ...` is a separate expression that will always be true (not a comparison to the input).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comment that one issue is the return on the second line preventing the remaining code from executing. I also agree with the previous comment that using the .lower() would probably be cleaner code then checking for both the situations of lowercase 'mage' and the first letter being capital 'Mage'. By using .lower() you don't need to check both situations of 'mage' and 'Mage' as no matter how it is typed even if it is typed like: 'mAgE' then the code would still work.

However, I have one idea to get the code to work in a similar way that you have it set up.

You could also try:

```
if character_class_option == "mage" or character_class_option == "Mage"
```

In addition, I don't think it is necessary use str() on something that is already a string. However, I can understand you may have done this in an attempt to debug.